# Freshchat push notification via Firebase (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm implementing a third part service in my app (FreshChat,a service that let you integrate an helpdesk in an app or website),and all is going fine,except for the push notifications for chats. Freshchat work via Firebase (And the firebase push notifications don't give problems) but freshat notifications don't work. I followed the official documentation of freshchat but there are deprecated methods and definitely don't work (I tryed a lot)

Here's the Firebase Cloud Messaging code:

```
 public class FireBase  extends FirebaseMessagingService {




@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) {
    super.onMessageReceived(message);


    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channel_id")
            .setContentTitle(message.getNotification().getTitle())
            .setContentText(message.getNotification().getBody())
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle())
            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());


}
```

And the extract from FreshChat documentation:

7.1 Connecting Freshchat with FCM

If you haven’t already integrated FCM, do so by following the instructions here. After following FCM steps for integration, follow these 2 steps to connect Freshchat and FCM

Step 1. Send Registration TokenIn the app’s implementation of  FirebaseInstanceIdService, send the token to Freshchat as follows

```
 Java
 @Override
 public void onTokenRefresh() {
 String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
 Freshchat.getInstance(this).setPushRegistrationToken(token);
  }
```

Step 2 : Handle FCM MessageIn the app’s implementation of  FirebaseMessagingService, pass the RemoteMessage object to Freshchat if it is a Freshchat notification.

```
 Java
 public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
 if (Freshchat.isFreshchatNotification(remoteMessage)) {
    Freshchat.getInstance(this).handleFcmMessage(context, remoteMessage);
 } else {
    //Handle notifications with data payload for your app
 }
 }
```

I tryed to do it via the documentation,but simply don't work,can you help me? Thank you in advance!
Here' also the full FreshChat documentation: https://support.freshchat.com/support/solutions/articles/229319-freshchat-android-sdk-integration-steps

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this in your default activity, it works for me.

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
           .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
               @Override
               public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                   if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                     Log.e(TAG, "getInstanceId failed", task.getException());
                     return;
                   }
                   // Get new Instance ID token
                   String token = task.getResult().getToken();
                   Freshchat.getInstance(this).setPushRegistrationToken(token);
             
                   Log.e("Token", token.toString());
               }
           });
```

Hope this helps you. Happy coding!!